# Problem persisting collection of interfaces in JDO/Datanucleus. "unable to assign an object of type.."

Tags: jdo, datanucleus

I am getting below error whilst trying to persist an object that has a collection of interfaces which I want to hold a couple of different types of objects. Seems to be happening almost randomly. Sometimes after restarting it works ok ( I might be doing something wrong though).

```
class CommentList {

@Persistent
@Join
ArrayList<IComment> = new ArrayList<IComment>();

}
```

somewhere else...

```
CommentList cl = new CommentList();

cl.addComment( new SimpleComment() );
cl.addComment( new SpecialComment() );

repo.persist( cl );
```

I can see the join table has been created in my DB along with ID fields for each of the Implementation classes of IComment.

SimpleComment and SpecialComment implement IComment. If I just add a SimpleComment it works fine. As soon as I start trying to add other types of objects I start to get the errors.

error im getting

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Field "com.myapp.model.CommentList.comments" is a reference field (interface/Object) of type com.myapp.behaviours.IComment but DataNucleus is unable to assign an object of type "com.myapp.model.ShortComment" to this field. You can only assign this field to a type specified by the "implementation-classes" extension attribute.
at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.MultiMapping.setObject(MultiMapping.java:220)
at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.ReferenceMapping.setObject(ReferenceMapping.java:526)
at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.MultiMapping.setObject(MultiMapping.java:200)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.scostore.BackingStoreHelper.populateElementInStatement(BackingStoreHelpe
r.java:135)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.scostore.RDBMSJoinListStoreSpecialization.internalAdd(RDBMSJoinListStore
Specialization.java:443)
at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.scostore.JoinListStore.internalAdd(JoinListStore.java:233)
```

When it does save, if I restart the server and try to query for a list of the comments,  I get null values returned.

I'm using mysql backend - if I switch to db4o it works fine.

Please let me know if any info would be useful.

If you have any idea where I might be going wrong or can provide some sample code for persisting collection of different objects implementing the same interface that would be appreciated.

Thanks for any help.

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by specifying

```
<extension implemention-classes="SimpleComment SpecialComment"/>
```

for the field `cl` in my pacakge.jdo.

Answer (score 0):

When I used interfaces I just enabled dynamicSchemaUpdates (some persistence property with a name like that) and FK's are added when needed. The log gives all SQL I think